# Can not access my kubernetes cluster even if all my server certificates are valid

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I am trying to achieve that my kubernetes cluster should have a validity of 5 years, so I have made my **ca.crt, apiserver.crt, kubelet-client.crt, front-proxy.crt** of 5 years validity and placed those in **/etc/kubernetes/pki**.

Also, I have enabled my kubelet with client certificate rotation

```
Environment="KUBELET_CERTIFICATE_ARGS=--rotate-certificates=true --cert-dir=/var/lib/kubelet/pki --feature-gates=RotateKubeletClientCertificate=true"
```

So to verify my cluster is working fine I changed the date on my system to 1 day before 1 year expiration and certificate rotation are done properly

```
Oct 22 06:00:16 ip-10-0-1-170.ec2.internal kubelet[28887]: I1022 06:00:16.806115   28887 reconciler.go:154] Reconciler: start to sync state
Oct 22 06:00:23 ip-10-0-1-170.ec2.internal kubelet[28887]: I1022 06:00:23.546154   28887 transport.go:126] certificate rotation detected, shutting down client connections to start using new credentials
```

But once my cluster passes one year it starts showing the error on any kubectl get nodes/pods command:
"error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)"

The possible issue I can think is **/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf** has only one-year validity certificates. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you manually raise the cluster? through kubeadm?

Comment: Yes I am raising cluster through kubeadm and before doing kubeadm init , put all necessary certificates in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ so that kubeadm picks up my certs while bringing cluster up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a way to regenerate new admin.conf certificate before expiry of cluster

Generate admin.key and admin.csr using openssl

```
openssl genrsa -out admin.key 2048 
openssl req -new -key admin.key -out admin.csr -subj "/O=system:masters/CN=kubernetes-admin"
```

Now create CSR in kubernetes using above openssl admin.csr

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: admin_csr
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: $(cat admin.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - client auth
EOF
```

Now approve the CSR generated using
    kubectl certificate approve admin_csr

Now extract the admin.crt from approved CSR
    kubectl get csr admin_csr -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | base64 -d > admin.crt

Now change the current user and context to use the new admin key and certificates.

```
kubectl config set-credentials kubernetes-admin --client-certificate=/home/centos/certs/admin.crt  --client-key=/home/centos/certs/admin.key
kubectl config set-context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes --cluster=kubernetes --user=kubernetes-admin
```

After this step your kubeconfig which in my case is /root/.kube/config has new client certificate data and key.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your `client-certificate`(**/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf**) is generated for one year. You can generate your client certificate using following command:

```
kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig admin --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki --kubeconfig-dir /etc/kubernetes/
```

Comment: [root@ip-10-0-1-170 pki]# kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig admin --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki --kubeconfig-dir /etc/kubernetes/
```unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.10.txt": Get https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.10.txt: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid```

I am getting above error when running the command.

Comment: what is your minikube version? and also please specify the cluster version.

Comment: I am using kubeadm to deploy k8s cluster and kubernetes version 1.10.3. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> **verified to work with K8s / kubeadm versions `v1.14.x`**

Make sure to perform these steps on every control plane node:

- to manually regenerate certificates, use the following

  ```
  # all certs
  kubeadm alpha certs renew all

  # individual cert
  # see `kubeadm alpha certs renew --help` for list
  kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver-kubelet-client
  ```

  here's a helpful script to automate checking cert expiration, and renew if expired: https://gist.github.com/anapsix/974d6c51c7691af45e33302a704ad72b
- to regenerate `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` config, one can use the following command, which is evidently a heavily guarded secret, since I was unable to find any documentation mentioning crucial `--org system:masters` part

  ```sh
  kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user \
    --org system:masters \
    --client-name kubernetes-admin
  ```

---

`kubeadm` in K8s `v1.15.x` has new helpful capabilities.

Make sure to perform these steps on every control plane node:

- to check expiration

  ```
  kubeadm alpha certs check-expiration
  ```
- to renew (for example cert in `scheduler.conf`)

  ```
  kubeadm alpha certs renew scheduler.conf
  ```